# Celery/Kombu ignoring run_every

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, kombu, celerybeat

I'm kombu/celery setup that I've recently deployed. The tasks execute fine, but appear to run almost continuously rather than respecting the run_every attribute. Perhaps more oddly, this behavior only appears in production and works fine locally.

My `tasks.py` looks like this:

```
from celery.task import  PeriodicTask
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

class FirstTask(PeriodicTask):
    run_every = timedelta(seconds = 30)
    # Do Stuff
```

My `settings.py` includes

```
BROKER_URL = "django://"

import djcelery  
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

plus `'djcelery'` and `'kombu.transport.django'`in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

And in production I run `python manage.py celeryd -v 2 -B -s celery -E -l INFO` to start running my tasks. I had been following Chase Seibert's [tutorial](http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2010/07/djangocelery-quickstart-or-how-i.html) if that clears anything else up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does the task take to finish? And have you tried clearing your queue before trying it again (celery might not respect the `run_every` setting, if you have already tasks in your queue...)

Comment: Ha ha: `Purged 5625 messages from 1 known task queue.` That probably has something to do with it. How do they pile up like that?

Comment: Did you try it with different intervals or different code before? Or did the task take too long to execute? Also if you have a lot of other  celery tasks they could delay the execution of your periodic task (don't take the `run_every` interval for granted!)

Answer (score 0):

why do you include 'kombu.transport.django' in your INSTALLED_APPS..? I thought celery and kombu are providing the same functionality.